# What is maxium number of api that can be developed in wso2 apim

Tags: wso2-api-manager, wso2, wso2-enterprise-integrator, wso2-esb

Good Day everyone

I wanted to know maximum number of api that can can developed and deployed in wso2 apim
Just wanted to know maximum range of apis that can published and range depends on what factor of wso2

Please help me know. About this
And question is out of curiosity

Comment: Are you specifically looking for a number? There are few deployment modes. Based on it this number can be vary. You can have a single gateway or have multiple gateway based on any logical separation. Or you can have per tenant gateways, etc

Answer (score 0):

There is no max limit set for number of APIs that can be created in API Manager. I have personally seen deployments with thousands of APIs. When you create more APIs you will have to scale the deployment proportionally.(Horizontal and vertical scaling).

Having said that, the performance varies in real world deployments due to many reasons. So the best way to determine whether API Manager can cater your load is to do a load test with the actual infrastructure you are planning to use.

Also some performance matrics can be found in the following link.

[1] - https://apim.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/install-and-setup/setup/deployment-best-practices/performance-tests-results/